# table view with dynamic table rows and with NSLayoutConstraint’s programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nslayoutconstraint

I implemented a table view with dynamic table rows and with NSLayoutConstraint’s programmatically. However, I encounter differences between the iPhone 5/5s/6s and iPhone 6s plus simulator.

What I basically did:

- Creating a UIView (containerView) on a ScrollView (scrollView)
- Creating a UITableView (infoTableView) on the containerView
- Defining dynamic row heights for infoTableView
- Registering a UITableViewCell (InfoTableViewCell) on infoTableView
- Creating two UILabels (infoLabel and infoText) on a InfoTableViewCell
- Defining horizontal and vertical constraints to infoText

When running this code below on an iPhone 5/5s/6s simulator the table row height is determined properly, and the labels are properly constrained to the table row. However, when I simulate the code on an iPhone 6 the data is not displayed correctly.

See [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCfCF.png).
How could this difference be explained? Are the constraints set correctly? Or am I missing some code?

A related question is about the total tableview height. I set this height in viewDidLayoutSubviews, but it is currently set to constant value since the TableHeight seems not yet been initialized here. How should the height be determined?

I hope that anybody could help.

My code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UIScrollViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var scrollView : UIScrollView!
    var containerView : UIView!
    var infoTableView: UITableView!

    var infoLabels = [String]()
    var infoData = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        scrollView = UIScrollView()
        scrollView.delegate = self
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(view.bounds.width, 1000)

        containerView = UIView()

        infoLabels = ["Label1", "Label2", "Label3"]
        infoData = ["Label1Test1 Label1Test2 Label1Test3 Label1Test4 Label1Test5",
                    "Label3Test1 Label2Test2 Label2Test3 Label2Test4 Label2Test5",
                    "Label3Test1 Label3Test2 Label3Test3 Label3Test4 Label3Test5"]

        // Create information TableView
        infoTableView = UITableView()
        infoTableView.registerClass(InfoTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        infoTableView.delegate      =   self
        infoTableView.dataSource    =   self
        infoTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 25
        infoTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        containerView.addSubview(infoTableView)

        scrollView.addSubview(containerView)
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
    }


    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        scrollView.frame = view.bounds
        containerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, scrollView.contentSize.width, scrollView.contentSize.height)

        // --------------------------------------------
        // How to determine height of table view??????
        let infoTableHeight: CGFloat = 200
        //infoTableView.frame.size.height => Is nil during initialization!!!
        infoTableView.frame = CGRectMake(5, 50, self.view.bounds.width - 10, infoTableHeight)
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return infoData.count
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let textCellIdentifier = "Cell"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(textCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! InfoTableViewCell

        let infoLabel = infoLabels[indexPath.row]
        let infoDataItem = infoData[indexPath.row]

        cell.infoLabel.text = infoLabel
        cell.infoText.text = infoDataItem
        cell.selectionStyle = .None
        return cell
    }
}



class InfoTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var infoLabel = UILabel()
    var infoText = UILabel()

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String!) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        infoText.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left
        infoText.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14)
        infoText.baselineAdjustment = .AlignCenters
        infoText.numberOfLines = 0
        infoText.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        infoText.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
        self.contentView.addSubview(infoText)

        let views = ["infoText" : infoText]
        let hConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-[infoText]-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: views)
        self.contentView.addConstraints(hConstraint)

        let vConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-[infoText]-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: views)
        self.contentView.addConstraints(vConstraint)

        infoLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left
        infoLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(14)
        infoLabel.baselineAdjustment = .AlignCenters
        infoLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        self.contentView.addSubview(infoLabel)
    }

    required init(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: decoder)!
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        let width = frame.width-120
        let height = frame.size.height

        infoLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 0, 100, height)
        infoText.frame = CGRectMake(110, 0, width, height)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you setting the frame of the labels in layoutSubviews if you've used AutoLayout to constrain them? And what's pinning the infoLabel?

Comment: I thought that the frame definition in viewDidLayoutSubviews could be considered as an initialization. However, removing the frame definition for infoText, and adjusting the constraint properties solved the problem! I did not define constraints for infoLabel since the content always fits the frame initialized in viewDidLayoutSubviews. I don’t know whether this is good practice, but it seems to work.
Do you also know how to determine the total table height after the height of the individual row are changed based on their content?

Comment: You could use the `contentSize` property of the tableview. However by definition tableviews are intended to scroll... perhaps you may be better off with a stack view?